# Rudimentary Access to webdata (html) through socket (port 80) connection using Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

My question is theoretical: we can use the **urllib library (urlopen)** to return a html page; I understand that `data = mysock.recv(512)` behaves as `document.read()` for the received data(UTF-8 or ASCII).

What code in the below lines operates as `open('document')` function?
`open('document')` locates the file specified and checks if it exists, my guess is `mysock.send(cmd)` is the equivalent since it sends the GET request to the webserver to procure the specified file from the address.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

**Edit:** I've seemed to have found an answer, but a more thorough reasoning is left wanting.

Answer (score 1):

After careful study, the right answer to this is: `mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))` behaves similarly to `open('romeo.txt')`; though it enables only connecting to the host domain through the port 80, and `open()` differs as it locates the existence of **'romeo.txt'** in defined location.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that http `GET` method searches the file on the server. In https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/http-server-what-do-you-need-to-know-to-build-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch-d1ef8945e4fa is an example implementation of `GET` method in C :

> GET /info.html HTTP/1.1
>
> So, **we just have to search for the info.html file in current
>   directory** (as `/` specifies that it is looking in the root directory of
>   the server. If it is like /messages/info.html then we have to look
>   inside messages folder for info.html file).

source : https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/http-server-what-do-you-need-to-know-to-build-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch-d1ef8945e4fa

The linux implementation of http protocol is similar ...

So `mysock.send(cmd)` is similar to `open(document)` because with it the `GET` is send that causes the server to search the file / check if it exists

Comment: Thanks for the deliberation; I felt that mysock.send(cmd) is more close to open('document'); however, the quiz I'm graded on shows mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80)) as answer :/